# Peut-on dire : « Vous pouvez également charger le produit sans avoir à l’allumer » ?

Tags: vocabulaire, choix-de-mot

Est-ce que c'est correct de dire:

> Vous pouvez également recharger le produit sans avoir à l’allumer.

Est-ce qu'il y a une autre façon d'exprimer cette phrase?

Comment: Il faudrait connaître le contexte, le produit et la procédure d'utilisation à décrire pour trouver d'autres formulations.

Answer (score 2):

La formulation proposée est parfaitement correcte, *allumer* est un terme qui convient très bien.

Si la question de reformulation porte sur la construction « sans avoir à », voici une autre façon de dire la même chose :

> Vous pouvez également recharger le produit sans qu'il soit nécessaire de l’allumer.

Comment: Ou encore plus (trop ?) court : `Vous pouvez également recharger le produit sans l'allumer`

Answer (score 1):

Au lieu de: *sans avoir à l'allumer*, je dirais plutôt: *en le laissant éteint*, ou si la distinction existe: *en le laissant en veille*.

Comment: Ce qui est valable quelque soit l'énergie utilisée par le "produit". Abdelhafid n'a pas précisé le contexte.